# Please help me about OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have class User.

```
class User {
    public function like($name) {
        // This code will return the variable $name
    }
    public function unlike($name) {
        // This code will return the variable $name
    }
}
```

How to call class User like this

```
     User::like('Udin')->unlike('Asep');
```

Comment: `::` used for calling static members / function. Not for calling actual members / functions.

Comment: There is no substitute for **learning**: http://php.net/oop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a *fluent* API. You can do it like:

```
class User {
    public function like($name) {
        // This code will return the variable $name
        return $this;
    }
    public function unlike($name) {
        // This code will return the variable $name
        return $this;
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->like("John")->unlike("Mary");
```

Using static calls (`::` instead of `->`) is probably not a good idea because you don't have a `$this` anymore. I'm not sure what `User` would look like in that case.

Comment: with some kind of singleton pattern and a static `getInstance()` method it's possible like `(User::getInstance())->like()->unlike();` or `(new User)->like()->unlike();` is also possible. But like you said,.. I don't like static's either.

Comment: Why do you need it? `->` (non-static) is better.. better to handle, better to test and debug

Comment: Apart from the 'var' (which generates a syntax error) on line 12 this answer seems to be right.

Comment: Ha! :D Too much JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "`->`" sign to acces members of instance of a class, instead of class methods.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really want that you can make it like this! but it's quite sad lol.

Would be ok if you use a factory as static and then you initialize the User class, but that is another story, and i'm sure plenty of users will complain about it *.*

```
   class User {

        public static function like($name) {
            echo $name.'<br/>';
            return new User();
        }

        public function unlike($name) {
            echo $name.'<br/>';;
        }
    }

    User::like('foo')->unlike('teste');
```